# Android: how to get the hex offset of an integer

Tags: android, hex, offset, type-conversion

Is there a way to get the 2 offsets of an integer?

For example if i have:

```
int a= 5;
int b= 300;
```

I need a way to get the hex offsets of these 2 numbers:

```
String offseta_1 = "00";
String offseta_2 = "05";
String offsetb_1 = "01";
String offsetb_2 = "2c";
```

or

```
int offseta_1_int = 0;
int offseta_2_int = 5;
int offsetb_1_int = 1;
int offsetb_2 = 44;
```

How can accomplish this in android?

Comment: Do you mean a simple transformation Int to hex-String and hex-String back to Int?

Comment: no. i need the 2 byte offset of the number. if the int number has only 1 byte (does not exceed 255) then i get the upper offset 00 and lower the hex of that number ex:5=0x0005. if the int exceeds 255 then the upper and lower offsets represents that number. ex: 300=0x012c

Comment: Now I´m understanding what you want - sorry. So just set you min and max and then convert it. in the end it just should be 1 or 2 If-Statements.

Answer (score 0):

Converting DEC-INTEGER to HEX-STRING:

```
int i = 55;
String hexString = Integer.toHexString(i);  // = "0x37" OR "37"
```

Converting HEX-STRING to DEC-INTEGER:

```
// can be lower- and uppercase
// "0x" is optional, but hex-numbers should be marked like this
String hexString = "0xAF";
int decimalInt = Integer.parseInt(hexNumber, 16);  // = 175
```

Comment: i know this but i need to have the 2 offsets (upper and lower). if thr number in integer is 55 then the upper offset would be 00 and the lower would be 37. i need some kind of function that can determine  this. wither number exceeded 255.